# How to record the time(seconds) for which an activity is active?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, android-activity

I am making a simple quiz application. Inside app, there is a question activity, where 10 questions are being displayed and the scores are given subsequently. Now I want to record the time duration user is taking to attempt all the 10 questions.
I have added a timer for each question of 10 seconds. Now I need score and the time duration of attempting all the questions.

I needed this because if the two users have the same number of correct answers then I will able to rank them on the basis of their time duration.
Thanks & Please Help!!

Comment: Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: All details have been mentioned in the question @Andreas

Comment: You don't have any MCVE or any attempt at recording the total duration

Answer (score 0):

Start a timer in `onCreate()` or `onResume()` and then store the count and when you stop the timer you have your score.

I would probably extend or just modify CountDownTimer.